# How can I unit test Nancy modules with F#?

Tags: unit-testing, f#, nancy

I'm trying to test Nancy modules with F# as described [here](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Testing-your-application), the thing is I can't see how to pass the second parameter in F#.

Here's what I have so far:

```
let should_return_status_ok_for_get() =
    let bootstrapper = new DefaultNancyBootstrapper()    
    let browser = new Browser(bootstrapper, fun req -> req.Accept(new Responses.Negotiation.MediaRange("application/json")))    
    let result = browser.Get("/Menu", fun req ->  req.HttpRequest())
    Assert.AreEqual (HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode)
    result
```

in the example, I should be able to instantiate a Browser object to test a specific Module:

```
var browser = new Browser(with => with.Module(new MySimpleModule()));
```

But I get a compile time error in F# when I try:

```
let browser = new Browser(fun req -> req.Module(new MenuModule()))
```

**EDIT** Error: No overloads match for method 'Browser'

Are there any examples of this in F#?
Also, is this the best way to go about this in F#?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: most likely you just have to add `new Browser(Action<_> (fun req -> req.Module ...))` to get it working - the conversion between `fun` and `Action` is sadly not as nice as in C# (and maybe you have to help out with the types instead of `_` there)

Comment: @Carsten, I've tried that and still no luck. I've resorted to writing a Browser Factory in C#, that simply returns browser for the module I want. I call it with: let browser = NancyBrowserFactory.Create<MenuModule>(); // until I learn enough about this in F#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I run Nancy tests in F#:

I create a new bootstrapper in my test project by deriving from the `DefaultNancyBootstrapper`. I use this bootstrapper to register my mocks:

```
type Bootstrapper() =
    inherit DefaultNancyBootstrapper()

    override this.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container : TinyIoCContainer) =
        base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container)    
        container.Register<IMyClass, MyMockClass>() |> ignore
```

Then I write a simple test method to execute a GET request like so:

```
[<TestFixture>]
type ``Health Check Tests`` () =    

    [<Test>]
    member test.``Given the service is healthy the health check endpoint returns a HTTP 200 response with status message "Everything is OK"`` () =
        let bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper()
        let browser = new Browser(bootstrapper)

        let result = browser.Get("/healthcheck")
        let healthCheckResponse = JsonSerializer.deserialize<HealthCheckResponse> <| result.Body.AsString()

        result.StatusCode            |> should equal HttpStatusCode.OK
        healthCheckResponse.Message  |> should equal "Everything is OK"
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: So it isn't possible to use the Browser constructor overloads with strongly typed modules. I think doing it this way is better as you end up testing the assumed routing as well